# error: supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies

Tags: java, kotlin, classpath

Have a very basic Java/Kotlin dependency issue when we have chained dependencies. I posted a similar question before, but now I removed Gradle from the equation and tried directly with java/kotlin. Have

```
Main --> Lib2 --> Lib1
```

Lib1.java:

```
package com.test.lib1;

public interface Lib1 {
}
```

Lib2.java:

```
package com.test.lib2;

public interface Lib2 extends com.test.lib1.Lib1 {
    public String msg = "Hello message from Lib2";
}
```

JavaMain.java:

```
package com.test.main;

import com.test.lib2.Lib2;

public class JavaMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("++++ Java TEST: " + Lib2.msg);
    }
}
```

When I run this, it works and prints `++++ Java TEST: Hello message from Lib2`. However when I build this Kotlin program compilation fails.

KotlinTest.kt:

```
package com.test.main

import com.test.lib2.Lib2

fun main() {
    println("++++ KT TEST: " + Lib2.msg)
}
```

Error I get: `"error: supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath: class com.test.lib2.Lib2, unresolved supertypes: com.test.lib1.Lib1".`

Here is the shell script I used to build/run:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

rm -rf build1 build2
mkdir build1 build2

echo "Building Lib1 ..."
javac -d build1 Lib1.java
(cd build1; jar cvf Lib1.jar *; cd ..)

echo "Building Lib2 ..."
javac -cp build1 -d build2 Lib2.java
(cd build2; jar cvf Lib2.jar *; cd ..)

if [ "$1" == "kotlin" ]; then
    echo ""
    echo "Building kotlin program ..."
    kotlinc -cp build2 KotlinTest.kt
    #kotlinc -cp build2:build1 KotlinTest.kt
    kotlin com.test.main.KotlinTest
else
    echo ""
    echo "Building java program ..."
    rm -rf main
    mkdir main
    javac -cp build2/Lib2.jar -d main JavaMain.java

    echo "Running Java program ..."
    java -cp build2/Lib2.jar:main com.test.main.JavaMain
fi
```

Why Java and Kotlin are behaving differently? The fact that Lib2 uses Lib1 shouldn't be entirely contained with Lib2, and the Main class shouldn't be worrying about Lib1 at all? Java version tried both 1.8 and 11, Kotlin version `1.7.21`.

Comment: Why are you including Lib2.jar in the classpath when running the Java version, but not when running the Kotlin version?

Comment: @gidds comparison is at the compilation step. For example, `javac -cp build2/Lib2.jar -d main JavaMain.java` works but if I replace javac with kotlinc and the source file name as in `kotlinc -cp build2/Lib2.jar -d main KotlinTest.kt` I see the error.